# why the first-letter doesn't work when I add the div::before?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, pseudo-element

I want to change the color of the first letter "E" in "Elzero" without change the HTML script, but when I use `div::first-letter {color: #f44336}` the color don't changes unless I delete the :before pseudo element. Why?
I tried to add !important : `div::first-letter {color: #f44336 !important;}` but it doesn't change.

this is the code:

```css
div::first-letter {
  color: #f44336;
}

div {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #eee;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0px;
  padding-top: 25px;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
  font-size: 48px;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: 7px;
  position: relative;
  border-right: 10px solid #673ab7;
  border-left: 10px solid #f44336;
}

div::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  background-image: linear-gradient( to right, #f44336 0%, #f44336 20%, #2196f3 20%, #2196f3 40%, #4caf50 40%, #4caf50 60%, #e91e63 60%, #e91e63 80%, #673ab7 80%, #673ab7 100%);
}

div::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  background-image: linear-gradient( to right, #f44336 0%, #f44336 20%, #2196f3 20%, #2196f3 40%, #4caf50 40%, #4caf50 60%, #e91e63 60%, #e91e63 80%, #673ab7 80%, #673ab7 100%);
}
```

```html
<div>Hello</div>
```

I want to make like this design:
[image: expected result]

Comment: Your code seems to work.

Comment: Firefox doesn't apply the color to the first letter because of the :before pseudo. remove it and use the gradient inside the div and size it via background-size + no-repeat.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid disturbing firefox *(??choose which :  first-letter or stick to the pseudo ?!?)* Use the gradient straight inside the div.

example

```css
div::first-letter {
  color: #f44336;
}

div {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0px;
  padding-top: 25px;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
  font-size: 48px;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: 7px;
  position: relative;
  border-right: 10px solid #673ab7;
  border-left: 10px solid #f44336;
  background: linear-gradient( to right, #f44336 0%, #f44336 20%, #2196f3 20%, #2196f3 40%, #4caf50 40%, #4caf50 60%, #e91e63 60%, #e91e63 80%, #673ab7 80%, #673ab7 100%) 0 0 / 100% 10px no-repeat;
  background-color: #eee;
}



div::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  background-image: linear-gradient( to right, #f44336 0%, #f44336 20%, #2196f3 20%, #2196f3 40%, #4caf50 40%, #4caf50 60%, #e91e63 60%, #e91e63 80%, #673ab7 80%, #673ab7 100%);
}
```

```html
<div>Hello</div>
```

note: both gradient can be added inside the div itself, dropping pseudos for something else.

Answer (score 0):

Use border-image and simplify your code:

```css
.box::first-letter {
  color: #f44336;
}

.box {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #eee;
  text-align: center;
  padding:25px 0px;
  font-size: 48px;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: 7px;
  border:10px solid;
  border-image:linear-gradient( 90deg, #f44336 20%, #2196f3 0 40%, #4caf50 0 60%, #e91e63 0 80%, #673ab7 0) 10
}
```

```html
<div class="box">Hello</div>
```